# Run gradle vert.x in the command line

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

I have this sample project: https://github.com/svprdga/web-reactive-frameworks-comparison/tree/master/vertx-ktorm

I want to run it from the CLI, but I can't.
I am trying to create the jar file, but when I run it, it prompts:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

> Task :compileKotlin
w: /home/svprdga/code/backend/web-reactive-frameworks-comparison/vertx-ktorm/src/main/kotlin/com/svprdga/vertxktorm/verticle/MainVerticle.kt: (18, 38): 'send(String!, Any!, ((AsyncResult<Message<T!>!>!) -> Unit)!): EventBus!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at com.svprdga.vertxktorm.Application$Companion.main(VertxKtorm.kt)
    at com.svprdga.vertxktorm.Application.main(VertxKtorm.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 2 more
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Gradle Application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) or [Gradle Shadow plguin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). Your issue is caused by incomplete class path when running a single JAR file. `from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }` seems to be not working.